# Can not use any Chrome API to listening events

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Certainly, this question is too crazy, but I can not find any solutions.

Detail of my code:

**manifest.json**

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "js": [ "ct.js" ],
    "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ]
 }],
"permissions": [ "management","storage","proxy", "*://*/*" ],
```

**ct.js**

```
chrome.management.onInstalled.addListener(function (info) {
    console.info(info);
});

chrome.management.onEnabled.addListener(function (info) {
    console.info(info);
});
```

I got an error result in Console

```
ct.js:58 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onInstalled' of undefined
```

I log `chrome` variable in Console

```
{
  app: Object
  csi: function()
  loadTimes: function()
  runtime: Object
  webstore: Object
  __proto__: Object
}
```

I'm stuck from 2 days ago. Any aid for me is a huge help for my life.

Sorry for my bad English. Thanks for watching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `chrome.management.*` API (or, for that matter, `chrome.runtime.onInstalled` event) [from a content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts); it's a less privileged context.

> However, content scripts have some limitations. They cannot:
>
> - Use chrome.* APIs, with the exception of:
>
>   - extension (getURL, inIncognitoContext, lastError, onRequest, sendRequest)
>   - i18n
>   - runtime (connect, getManifest, getURL, id, onConnect, onMessage, sendMessage)
>   - storage

You need to have a [background](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) or [event](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) script to handle it for you. If you need to react to it, or initiate something from a content script, [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) with background is the answer.